# Pyqt4, QtCore4.dll appcrash

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtcore, crash

I am making GUI application by Python, using PyQt4 and spynner. I have function:

```
def find_me(self, url, name=None, code=None):
    b = spynner.Browser()
    if name != None and code != None:
        b.create_webview()
        b.load(url)
        b.wk_fill('input[name="ctl00$cphBody$tbOrgName"]', name)
        b.wk_fill('input[name="ctl00$cphBody$OrganizationCode1$CodeTextBox"]', code)
        b.click('#ctl00_cphBody_btnSearch')
        b._wait_load()
        source = b.html
        b.destroy_webview()
        b.close()
    else:
        b.create_webview()
        b.load(url)
        source = b.html
        b.destroy_webview()
        b.close()
    return source
```

This function doing some moves on site and returning to me html code of page.
I have main function named "downloader":

```
def downloader(self):
    downloads_list = []
    uniq = []
    j = 0
    for name, code, checkstate in self.input_data:
        try:
            if checkstate == 0:
                source = self.find_me("http://bankrot.fedresurs.ru/DebtorsSearch.aspx",     name, code)
                root = XpathSelector(fromstring(source))
            else:
                new_name = name.split(" ")
                source = self.find_me2("http://bankrot.fedresurs.ru/DebtorsSearch.aspx", new_name[0], new_name[1], new_name[2], code)
                root = XpathSelector(fromstring(source))
    ......
    self.progress_bar.setValue(((j+1)*100)/len(self.input_data)) #setting value to progress bar
    j += 1
```

And i have third function that calling "downloader":

```
def print_keys(self):
    .................
    self.downloader()
```

This function connected to button:

```
self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.print_keys)
```

After this string in "downloader":

```
self.progress_bar.setValue(((j+1)*100)/len(self.input_data))
```

I have "Python.exe" appcrash. Reason : QtCore4.dll.

What i am doing wrong?Help me please.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself". Can you please provide a minimilistic working example that demonstrates the problem rather than small parts of a larger program. The crash could be due to any number of things which will be impossible to diagnose without some context.

Comment: My programm crashing because of "spynner". Without spynner i dont have any problems. But i need spynner to automate some moves.

Comment: That may be so, but you will still need to provide the code for a minimilistic working example that demonstrates the problem. Debugging this sort of thing without that is basically impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soved my problem by replacing spynner for Selenium+PhantomJS